# CakePHP nesting form helpers

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a form with a weight field and I'd like there to be an input for numbers and a select dropdown for units (lbs, kg etc..) and I'd like to write the result to the database on submit as a single varchar datatype e.g. '125 lbs'.  Is this possible with CakePHP form helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "possible with CakePHP form helpers" out of the box, in that Cake hasn't thought of that particular situation and catered for it.

But you know, the easiest (and also the best / most intelligent) way to handle this would be to just have two separate fields in your database - weight, and weight_units. Otherwise you'll be constantly splitting your single weight_with_units field into it's two parts as you pull it to and from the database. With two database fields, you can easily handle it with Cake's form helper.

Or, just be consistent and force users to always use the same metric; so you'd have one field, weight_in_pounds, which only stores the number (eg. 245), but you assume it's 245 pounds. Storing both the weight and it's metric in the same field is definitely not the way to go, though.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying to conserve space in my db, however this seems more logical.

Comment: Databases are pretty fast these days. It's pretty much never worth compromising good, sensible design in an attempt to save space / speed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like that you let the user choose the weight unit - pounds confuse me but I get that it is still used in the US. I only use pounds for butter and babies!

Splitting the data into two fields will give you flexibility in lots of ways and it's much, much cleaner.

You can, however, have two fields on the form (just make up names) and you then join them in the controller prior to saving - or in the model as a funky custom validation rule.